# How do can I grab everything from the first occurrence of Grid-ref to the last bit from a file which contains the data in the format below in js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I am learning to code in javascript and I have been task to extract data from a .pre text file which looks like below and insert the data into a 4 columned DB table which looks like this
Xref Yref Date Value
Xref is the value 1 from the Grid-ref=   1, 148 line etc
Yref is the value 148 from the Grid-ref=   1, 148 line etc
date is in the format 1/1/1991 where the first row of values represents Jan 1991 to Dec 1991, the second row Jan 1992 to Dec 1992 etc.
value is the corresponding value like this row
3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
I have written this code to read the file and sort of display it as an array, I now want to grab the bit of the file from the first occurrence of Grid-Ref to the bottom of the over 50,000 rows and then pull/transfer the data into the DB table format described above

I know how to create my own DB and use node js to get, pull, put, delete etc. What i am struggling with is the transform this data into the DB grabbing the correct bits using regex or something similar. You help will be greatly appreciated

````
Some sample text is here
.pre = precipitation (mm)
CRU TS 2.1
[Long=-180.00, 180.00] [Lati= -90.00,  90.00] [Grid X,Y= 720, 360]
[Boxes=   67420] [Years=1991-2000] [Multi=    0.1000] [Missing=-999]
Grid-ref=   1, 148
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
Grid-ref=   1, 311
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450```
````

Comment: The code that I write should have an option to specify the file name, read in the header data, transform the data, create the database table structure and insert the information into the database. I have done the first bit where my code specifies the file name read the .pre file

Comment: this is what I wrote ```const { readFileSync, promises: fsPromises } = require("fs");

function syncReadFile(filename) {
  const filecontent = readFileSync(filename, { encoding: "utf-8" });
//  console.log(filecontent);
  const array = filecontent
    .split(/\r?\n/)
    .map((row) => {
      return row.split(",");
    });
 
  console.log(array);
  return array;
}

syncReadFile("sample.pre");```